# Java generics set union casting

Tags: java, generics, casting

why does compiler shows "Cannot cast from Set<Number&Comparable<?>> to Set<Number>" on variable "numbers3" ?

```
    public static <E> Set<E> union (Set<? extends E> s1, Set<? extends E> s2) 
    {
        Set<E> temp = new HashSet<E>();

        temp.addAll(s1);
        temp.addAll(s2);

        return temp;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Set<Integer> integers = new HashSet<Integer>();
        integers.add(123);

        Set<Double> doubles = new HashSet<Double>();
        doubles.add(456.78);

        Set<Number> numbers1 =  TestClass.<Number>union(integers, doubles);
        Set<? extends Number> numbers2 =  TestClass.union(integers, doubles);
//      Set<Number> numbers3 =  (Set<Number>) (TestClass.union(integers, doubles)); <- Why does this not compile ?

        System.out.println(numbers1 + ", " + numbers2 + ", " /* + numbers3 */);
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's you java version?

Comment: It is Java 1.5 compliant and JRE is from WebSphere V8.5. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot cast from `Set<Number&Comparable<?>>` to `Set<Number>`

means, first, that without any other information, the compiler is inferring that the return type of `TestClass.union` should be `Set<Number&Comparable<?>>`, which is just the narrowest type the compiler can manage.

On the other hand, generally speaking, you can't cast from a `Set<SubFoo>` to a `Set<Foo>`.  That would let you add `Foo`s to a `Set<SubFoo>`, which would be bad.  So the compiler doesn't actually allow that cast.

All this means is that you need to do something different to make the compiler's type inference happy, which you've clearly already figured out how to do.